# NMAP sending ARP request to destination IP instead of default gateway

Tags: network, nmap, arp

I am doing an NMAP port scan to a remote IP present in a different subnet. NMAP initiates an ARP request first to the remote IP instead of the default gateway(even if the ARP entry is present in the ARP cache).

I want to understand the following things:

1. Why is NMAP sending an ARP request even though we have an ARP entry present?
2. Let's assume we don't have cache entry or NMAP is somehow not able to access Linux ARP cache; in that case,  why is NMAP
   sending ARP requests to remote IP instead of the default gateway

Note: I am able to ping to the same destination IP with the same interface. (Since ARP entry is present for that remote IP ping is not sending ARP instead of directly sending ICMP packets).

Please help me understand why NMAP is behaving in such a way for remote IPs

Tried --send-ip flag with NMAP, still observing ARP request being sent(to the remote IP)

Comment: What do you mean with "remote IP"? If you mean outside the local network (which is kind of implied since you are assuming that the traffic goes through the default gateway), then this question does not make any sense to me, since ARP does not span network boundaries. I therefore recommend that you describe your setup more clearly: what is your local network and your local IP, what system you are trying to scan, what are your exact commands, what are you exactly observing (packet capture) and what did you expect instead.